# Couldn't understand how closure works in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert( i );
    }, i * 100 ); 
}
```

I took the above example from the internet to understand closures. But I could not understand why it alerts value 5 for 5 times. Instead of alerting 1,2 3,4 ,5.
But the following way can be done. Can someone explain why. I am new to JavaScript so please provide some elaborate answers.

```
var createFunction = function( i ) {
    return function() {
        alert( i );
    };
};

for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    setTimeout( createFunction( i ), i * 100 );
}
```

Comment: actually  i need to understand how the above example work

Comment: In the same way as all others. Please read carefully a dozen of answers in the related question, and if you still have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: yeah  thanks but  i need to know why my 1 st example prints value 5, 5 times instead of printing 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Because `alert(i)` uses the `i` variable from the scope of a `for` loop, and not from the scope of a closure. In the second example you pass `i` to a function, which "locks" it inside on each iteration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17200991/918959

Comment: @VisioN you are confusing him too. There is no scope for a `for` loop.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala By scope of a `for` loop I mean the scope where the `for` loop is located.

Comment: cu both confuse me can u provide detail anser thanx